# Integration of $\int \sqrt{x\sqrt{2x}} dx$ and $\int 3^x e^x dx$

Tags: integration

I try to evaluate this two integrals, but I don't know how to proceed:

i) $\int \sqrt{x\sqrt{2x}} dx = \int {2^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot x^{\frac{3}{4}}}$

ii) $ \int 3^x e^x dx$

What's the best way to evaluate them? Substitution or Intergration by parts?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Should ii) be as in the title or as in the question?

Comment: as in the title, I edited it, thanks.

Comment: You don't solve integrals, you evaluate them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’ll do better with the first one if you correct the algebra:

$$\sqrt{x\sqrt{2x}}=\left(x(2x)^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(x\cdot2^{1/2}x^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(2^{1/2}x^{3/2}\right)^{1/2}=2^{1/4}x^{3/4}\;.$$

Now you have $\displaystyle\int2^{1/4}x^{3/4}~dx=2^{1/4}\int x^{3/4}~dx$, which is just a power rule integration.

In the second problem, use the fact that $3^xe^x=(3e)^x$; I’m sure that you’ve been shown how to integrate $a^x$ for a constant $a$.

You don’t need any special techniques for either of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited the mistake. And yes, I know how to integrate $a^x$. Thanks for the answer.